# HP dv6t gets super hot

Tags: hp-pavilion, intel-core-i7

I bought a HP dv6t quad edition notebook with core i7 about 2 days ago and from the time of first use, the notebook got warm and the temps reached 55-60 C while doing just web browsing. When I ran Cinebench 11.5, the temps reached up to 95 C. I am really very much concerned about the temps I am getting because I bought this laptop for gaming purposes and the cooling pad is also worthless.

I want to increase the fan speed so that the temps should not harm my CPU, but I don't know how to do that. I would love to do any thing to lower the temps with no compromise on the performance of the CPU.

Comment: There maybe some possible answers here, but it seems to have some thermal paste issues. You should get it replaced if possible, as it's been only 2 days.

Comment: Umer, check my edit to the answer below.

Comment: You do not seem to be the only one which experiences issues with a HP pavilion, I7's and heat. See http://superuser.com/questions/517003/intel-core-i7-quadcore-on-hp-pavilion-dv7-overheating-issues

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that on a laptop these things are locked. It's apparently [a common issue](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/HP-Dv6t-Overheats-a-lot/td-p/366339). You will have to go with the coolpad. Normally it should be sufficient, otherwise you are out of luck. You might want to take it back to the shop and demand a refund.

Also a tip: Your coolpad should have at least 3 fans and incline the laptop. I used to have a gaming laptop that ran on these temps and was able to reduce the temps with 10 - 15 degrees with a revoltec coolpad.

EDIT:

Also [see this link to see how one person cured the issue on that exact model](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/ALL-DV6t-i7-owners-if-you-have-poor-performance-click-here/m-p/1434637), it appears the heatsink was not attached properly at the factory.