# Intel Core i7 QuadCore on HP Pavilion dv7 Overheating Issues

Tags: cpu, overheating, hp-pavilion

I bought a brand new HP notebook: HP Pavilion dv7-6b21em BeatsAudio edition. The notebook is about 2 months old and has pretty nasty overheating problem.

I mainly use it for development however i do play some games. The disturbing thing is that the computer is loud on pretty simple tasks.

Here are the specs:

**CPU: Intel Core i7-2670QM QuadCore ( 8 threads ) @ 2.20 GHz

RAM: ( 8GB ) 2x 4GB @ 1066

HDD: 1TB 7200

GPU: ATI Radeon HD 6770M 1GB Dedicated DDR

OS: Windows 7 64bit Enterprise**

*I have an external monitor runing on VGA port an 22' Samsung SyncMaster S24B300*

CPU Heat Statistics

**Platform: rPGA 988B (Socket G2)

Frequency: cca. 3000 Mhz

VID: 1.1809 - 1.2059 v

Revision: D2

CPUID: 0x206A7

TDP: 45.0 Wats, Lithographu: 32 nm**

**Heat:**
Tj. Max: 100*C, Power 4.5  - 5.9 Wats
**Core #0: 63*C   Load on all is about 0 to 2%

Core #1: 65*C

Core #2: 66*C

Core #3: 67*C**

I opened the notebook the fan is working fine there is no dust but still right now the fan is pretty loud even tho all i have open is FireFox. When i run a game the heat jumps to whopping **90-97*C**. It has not shut down due to overheating yet but the loud fan is pretty annoying considering I'm not really doing anything stressfull.

Is there anything i can do to fix this is it maybe a BIOS issue ? I have all drivers updated tho to the latest. I have very few background processes running consuming bare 2GB of RAM and about 2% of CPU.

I had it serviced they said there is nothing wrong with it. But i feel that a Notebook that costs 1.2k Euros cant be like this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a dual screen configuration? if is the case, your gpu runs at max speed always (consider that your gpu has to deal with the double ammount of pixels). Try to use just one monitor (setting the main monitor on the radeon settings) when playing games, i have a similar laptop as yours and when i unplug the external monitor the gpu runs a bit more cooler. Also try to dont cover the intake vents of your laptop.

It's a shame, but is expected to always be overheating problemms on this kind of laptops. Also considering the fact that HP notebooks design doesnt always worry of the air flow.

Also consider that 60 C stock is normal, if your ambiental temperature is about 25-30 C degrees.